# Loop is creating array when iterated two times but creating string when iterated only one time in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, http, redirect

I have following code in `test.php`:

```
<?php
$url = "http://pars.mp3hunt.me/r1.php";

$again = 1;

while ($again == 1) {
    $headers = get_headers($url, 1);
    preg_match('/\b([3]\d\d)\b/', $headers[0], $matches); // 3XX error
    if (count($matches) > 0) {
        $url = $headers['Location'];
    } else {
        $again = 0;
    }
}
if (is_array($url)) {
    echo 'yes';
}
print_r($url);
?>
```

and redirects in `r1.php` `r2.php`. 
**`r1.php` has :**

```
<?php

$url="http://pars.mp3hunt.me/r2.php";
header('Location: ' . $url, true, 302);
?>
```

**`r2.php has**

```
<?php

$url="http://pars.mp3hunt.me/r3.php";
header('Location: ' . $url, true, 302);
?>
```

and `r3.php` has some text.

Now when `$url` variable is assigned `http://pars.mp3hunt.me/r1.php` the printed `$url` is an array and when it is assigned `http://pars.mp3hunt.me/r2.php` it is a string. The question is why it is so? I am assigning `$url` only strings everywhere. I have also not declared `$url` as an array and still after two redirects (iterations) it becomes an array and on one redirect (iterations) it is string.

Comment: The thing about PHP variables is that even if you don't declare one as an array but if it's assigned an array value it will be turned into an array.

Comment: From a quick glance, the answer to the why question relies in the return value of `get_headers`, some details of that (also related with streams) and with examples is here: https://hakre.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/head-first-with-php-streams/

Comment: Because `$headers['Location'];` is an array !!! So this line `$url = $headers['Location'];` makes `$url` into an array

Comment: @RiggsFolly: Yes, but it is not always an array. It depends on the number of redirects in the request chain.

Comment: `$header['Location'];` is a string and you can check it `if(is_array($headers['Location'])){
    echo 'yes header is array';
   }`

Comment: Then you will have to change your code to check if its an array before doing anything with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe is the normal behaviour. As you're dealing with redirects here, there can be more than one request with [`get_headers`](http://php.net/get_headers) as it performs a HTTP GET request by default.

With the `http://pars.mp3hunt.me/r2.php` URL you see a single location entry (and therefore a string) but with the `http://pars.mp3hunt.me/r1.php` URL you see two location entries (and therefore an array).

See [the link I've left in the comment](https://hakre.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/head-first-with-php-streams/) on how you can parse the result of `get_headers` and/or on how you control the behaviour (e.g. do a HTTP HEAD request instead of a GET request). There is also additional information available on Stackoverflow about this already.

Example:

```
$urls = [
    "http://pars.mp3hunt.me/r2.php",
    "http://pars.mp3hunt.me/r1.php"
];

foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $headers = get_headers($url, 1);

    echo $url, ":\n";
    var_dump($headers['Location']);
    echo "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
http://pars.mp3hunt.me/r2.php:
string(29) "http://pars.mp3hunt.me/r3.php"

http://pars.mp3hunt.me/r1.php:
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(29) "http://pars.mp3hunt.me/r2.php"
  [1]=>
  string(29) "http://pars.mp3hunt.me/r3.php"
}
```

Comment: Ok that helped me. Thanks